# Bash script sorting of lines in file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Hi im writing a bash script I need to remove blank space and sort the number in ascending anyone can help?

```
for line in `sed '/^$/d' $userInput`;
    myarray[$index]="$line"
    index=$(($index+1))
```

Currently im using the code above to remove blank space but I am not able to sort it.
`$userInput` is the file. the file contain few lines of number e.g.

```
1,4,5,6,2,3
```

Comment: Use the `sort` command to sort data.

Comment: At the moment you are trying to fill `myarray` with the values 1,4,5.... Have you set `index` first?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Barmar I tried line=$(echo "$line"|sort -n)
        echo "$line" but it is still not sorted.

Comment: You need to translate the `,` characters to newlines, since `sort` sorts lines, not within a single line.

Comment: @KangChen : _Currently im using the code above_  I don't think that you are using **that** code which you have posted in any way, since it is syntactically wrong and bash wouldn't accept it: You are writing a `for` loop, but there is neither `do` nor `done`. If you are looking for help for extending an existing program, please post a **working** program.

Answer (score 1):

If you have perl, and assuming `index` is zero-based, you could do:

```
declare -a myarray=($(
  perl -F, -laE '/\S/ and say join ",", sort map {$_+0} @F' "$userInput"
))
index=${#myarray[@]}
```

The Perl script does:

- read input from file `$userInput`
- `-F,` : set comma as delimiter for autosplit option
- `-l` : don't treat newline character as part of line
- `-a` : autosplit input lines into array `@F`
- `-E` : program follows
- `/\S/ and` : require input line contains non-whitespace (if not true, following command is skipped)
- `map {$_+0} @F` : try to convert elements of`@F` to numeric (ie. strip whitespace) (denote result as `@r1`)
- `sort @r1` : sort the elements of `@r1` (denote result as `@r2`)
- `join ",", @r2` : construct comma-delimited string from  elements of `@r2` (denote result as `@r3`)
- `say @r3` : output `@r3` with trailing newline

The lines output by the Perl script are used as elements of a new bash array `myarray`. Finally, we set `index` from the number of elements in `myarray`.